# Deploy java 11 app to GAE standard with gcloud CLI

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I want to deploy a spring boot jar using the gcloud CLI. When I run `gcloud app deploy` it does not upload the jar file:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
```

When I run the gradle deploy command it also tells me that it uploaded one file. I assume that is the jar file that is missing.

```
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
```

When I look at whats going on in cloud build, I see that it is fetching a manifest.json which looks like that:

```
{
    "app.yaml": {
        "sourceUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.some- project.appspot.com/some-hash",
        "sha1Sum": "some-hash"
    },
    "source-context.json": {
        "sourceUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.some-project.appspot.com/some-hash",
    "sha1Sum": "some-hash"
    }
}
```

When I see check how that manifest.json looks like when I deploy it with the gradle plugin, I see that it includes a reference to the jar file like:

```
"my-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar": {
    "sourceUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.some-project.appspot.com/some-hash",
    "sha1Sum": "some-hash"
}
```

What do I miss to configure?

Comment: Could you please specify what is your issue or what were you expecting?

Comment: Regarding what you want to achieve I've found [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-google-app-engine) on how to deploy a Spring Boot App to GAE